# How to find the largest eigenvector of a matrix?

Tags: c#, python, c++, math, pca

I am trying to implement this without success and I have to do this without using external modules numpy, etc. There are 3 modules in the app I am coding this, Python and C#, C++ but no other fancy libraries other than standard ones.

On a separate application, I used numpy's svd and it works very accurately. So I am using it to match my results. My method is PCA and everything is good up to this point. But after I calculate my symmetric covariance matrix, I don't know how to find the largest eigenvector.

The data set is always 3d points, x, y and z.

```
vector center;
for(point p in points):
    center += p;
center /= points.count;

sumxx = 0;
sumxy = 0;
sumxz = 0;
sumyy = 0;
sumyz = 0;
sumzz = 0;
for(point p in points):
    vector s = p - center;
    sumxx += s.x * s.x;
    sumxy += s.x * s.y;
    sumxz += s.x * s.z;
    sumyy += s.y * s.y;
    sumyz += s.y * s.z;
    sumzz += s.z * s.z;

matrix3 mat = invert(matrix3(sumxx, sumxy, sumxz, sumxy, sumyy, sumyz, sumxz, sumyz, sumzz));
vector n;
if (determinant(mat) > 0)
    normal = find_largest_eigenvalue
```

Comment: Maybe you should include in the question the answers to the questions that once were in comments here, especially the specifics on the matrix.

Comment: @Cimbali: Not sure why they were deleted but I will try to add what I remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us recap what you are asking, to clarify :

1. Find an eigenvector of a matrix `mat`
2. This eigenvector should be associated with the largest eigenvalue of the matrix
3. The matrix is the symmetric covariance matrix of a [principal component analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis). **In particular, it is symmetric.**
4. Your matrix is square **of size 3 by 3**, as shown in your code by `matrix3 mat = ...` and confirmed in a (now deleted) comment.

Under these very specific circumstances, the following answer applies. However tmyklebu warns against numerical instability of this approach for some pathological matrices, typically when `r` is close to `-1`.

---

Alright, lets start with a bit of reading from [wikipedia's page on Characteristic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial)

> In linear algebra, the characteristic polynomial of a square matrix is a polynomial, which is invariant under matrix similarity and has the eigenvalues as roots. [image: det(zI-A)]

blah blah blah, let's skip directly to the [3x3 matrix section in the page on Eigenvalue algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#3.C3.973_matrices).

> If A is a 3×3 matrix, then its characteristic equation can be expressed as:
>   [image: det(zI-A)]

Followed a few lines later by (more or less) this pseudo-code, **for symmetric matrices** (which you say you have, if I'm not mistaken -- otherwise you might have complex eigenvalues) :

```
p1 = A(1,2)^2 + A(1,3)^2 + A(2,3)^2
if (p1 == 0) 
   % A is diagonal.
   eig1 = A(1,1)
   eig2 = A(2,2)
   eig3 = A(3,3)
else
   q = (A(1,1) + A(2,2) + A(3,3)) / 3
   p2 = (A(1,1) - q)^2 + (A(2,2) - q)^2 + (A(3,3) - q)^2 + 2 * p1
   p = sqrt(p2 / 6)
   B = (1 / p) * (A - q * I)       % I is the identity matrix
   r = determinant(B) / 2

   % In exact arithmetic for a symmetric matrix  -1 <= r <= 1
   % but computation error can leave it slightly outside this range.
   if (r <= -1) 
      phi = pi / 3
   elseif (r >= 1)
      phi = 0
   else
      phi = acos(r) / 3
   end

   % the eigenvalues satisfy eig3 <= eig2 <= eig1
   eig1 = q + 2 * p * cos(phi)
   eig3 = q + 2 * p * cos(phi + (2*pi/3))
   eig2 = 3 * q - eig1 - eig3     % since trace(A) = eig1 + eig2 + eig3
end
```

So you want `max(eig1,eig2,eig3)` in the first case, `eig1` in the second case. Let us call `e` this largest eigenvalue.

For the eigenvector, you can now just solve `(A-e*I)x=0`

Comment: No, don't do that.  Finding eigenvalues via the characteristic polynomial is numerically unstable.

Comment: Yes.  It looks like you avoided most of the usual bugs here.  But in your code, an `r` close to `-1` leads to a `phi` around `M_PI/3` plus error on the order of **the square root of** the distance between `r` and `-1`.  This error perturbs `cos` by a similar amount  I took the bait and found a bad matrix for your code:  `[0x1.f1de4a71dea6p-1,-0x1.32245edca28p-4,0; -0x1.32245edca28p-4,0x1.af4cd633c31p-3,0; 0,0,0x1.f5965a029b8ap-1]`.  (Those numbers are in C99 hexfloat notation.)  Your approach only gets about 32 significant bits.

Comment: Double precision IEEE floating point numbers have 17 digits of precision.  That's it.

Comment: They have a 52 bit mantissa, if that's what you're trying to say. With 1 implicit bit that's a maximum precision of around 10^-16 (normalized for the exponent of course). So 32 bits in a pathological case is pretty bad, and certainly much worse than what you'd expect, but then the precision you need depends on the applications...

Answer (score 1):

There are different algorithms for finding eigenvalues.  Some work from smallest to largest, like QR; others work from largest to smallest, like power iteration or Jacobi-Davidson.

Maybe a switch of algorithm is what you want.  Try power method and see if that helps.

https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-calculate-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-general-matrix